# Jenkins API 403 error, Forbidden user cannot post path job/build

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I am trying to trigger a job via the Jenkins API using the following command:

```
curl -X POST https://<myserver>:8008/job/my-test-job/build?token=<mytoken>
```

I generated the token by clicking on my name->configure->credentials and adding a new credential and copying the resulting value here.

However, I get the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot post path \"/job/my-test-job/build\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {},
  "code": 403
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need a proper access token and Jenkins crumb in the request to remote trigger Jobs.

Following commands need curl and jq. Execute in the same session.

```
# Change the following appropriately
JENKINS_URL="http://localhost:8080"
JENKINS_USER=admin
JENKINS_USER_PASS=admin
```

**Get the Crumb**

```bash
JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS" -s --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
```

**Get the Access token**

```bash
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS" -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -s \
                    --cookie /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/me/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' \
                    --data 'newTokenName=GlobalToken' | jq -r '.data.tokenValue')
```

And then

```
curl -X POST -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -u $JENKINS_USER:$ACCESS_TOKEN "https://<myserver>:8008/job/my-test-job/build?token=<mytoken>"
```